# GhostScript PS to PDF converting - cropted some parts

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pdf-generation, ghostscript, postscript

I tried to convert Python Tkinter canvas to pdf. For that I used Ghostscript. Here is the code part,

```
canvas.postscript(file="tmp.ps",colormode='color')
somecommand = "gswin64c -o output.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -g57750x62070 - dPDFFitPage tmp.ps"
call(somecommand, shell=True)
```

The output pdf with large size but the pdf shows canvas GUI cropped and it is in bottom left corner of the pdf.

I want to show complete canvas on pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You've specified `-dPDFFitPage`, but your input file appears to be PostScript (judging by the '.ps' extension and your question title). `PDFFitPage` works with PDF input. Even using `-dPSFitPage` of the simpler `-dFitPage` will only work if the input PostScript program requests a media size. If it doesn't then the interpreter can't tell what its bounding box is, and so cannot scale it to fit the media.

You've also specified a media size in **pixels** (-g57750x62070) which is entirely inappropriate when the input and output are vector formats. For what it's worth, you are specifying a fixed media size of (approximately) 80 inches by 86 inches, using the default resolution of 720 dpi.

If all you want to do is turn a PostScript file into a PDF file then the simpler:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o out.pdf input.ps
```

is sufficient.